# Python Treeview Heading Overlap

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, ttk

Does anybody know a remedy to when a horizontal scrollbar is set to a ttk Treeview, the headings overlap the Treeview border? I tried looking into the ttk library file and finding the Treeview class, but could not figure out a method to fix this visual pet peeve. I also tried using ttk Style themes, which help conceal the overlap, but it still persists.

Image:
[Treeview Heading Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9W3Y.png)